# I would like to generate public key from Elliptic Curve cryptography ECC in place of RSA

Tags: c#, python-2.7

I have seen its implementations in various languages under name ECDH (diffie Hellman). I am confused diffie Hellman was to generate key pair to exchange shared secret.

Can i generate public key from it for node identification. Please help me in this regard.

Actually I am trying to implement CGA algorithm of ipv6 by making use of ECC in place of RSA to minimize the time for key generation.

Comment: just to clarify: (EC)DH is an anonymous key agreement protocol whereas (EC)RSA is a public key cryptosystem. even though both can be realized using elliptic curves, they are completely different things.

Comment: so I want to replace RSA with ECC for generating public key for a node..which ECC I have to use